# Question regarding Proper Mapping

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I'm reading toric variety from Cox et. al. and there is a theorem about proper mapping that I cant solve.

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous mapping of locally compact first
countable Hausdorff spaces. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) $f$ is proper

(b)Every sequence $(x_k)\in X$ such that $f(x_k)\in Y$ converges in $Y$ has a subsequence
$(x_{k_l})$ which converges in $X$.

This is the definition of Proper map.

A continuous mapping $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is proper if the inverse image $f^{-1}(T)$ is compact in $X$ for every compact subset $T \subseteq Y$.
It will great if you can give me some hints about how to solve it!

Comment: This is wrong: if $X$ is $\omega_1$ in the order topology (Locally compact Hausdorff and first countable among many things), and $f$ is a constant map  (to a singleton space $\{p\}$), $f$ obeys condition $(b)$ but not $(a)$ as $X = f^{-1}[\{p\}]$ is not compact.

Comment: You might consider dropping the AG and toric tags. While you read this theorem in a text on toric geometry, it is purely a result of general topology.

Answer (score 1):

(a) implies (b) is clear.

(b) implies (a): Recall that a subset $S\subset X$ is compact iff for every sequence $x_n$ in $S$, there is a convergent subsequence.

Let $T$ be a compact subset of $Y$. Let $S=f^{-1}(T)$. Given a sequence $x_n\in S$, $f(x_n)=y_n$ in $T$ has a convergent subsequence say $f(x_{n_k})=y_{n_k}$.

Now apply the condition (b) to the sequence $x_{n_k}$, so we get this one has a subsequence $x_{n_{k_r}}$ which is convergent in $X$ hence in $S$. So we are done.

Comment: I dont get the last part, where you are saying limit of $x_{n_k}$ is in S. Can you clarify that part. Thank you once again! You helped me on one of my question before also. Okay, you are saying that because S is closed

Comment: @user631697 Exactly. S is closed.

Comment: Another thing is, I am assuming you are saying X is a metrizable space, hence every compact set is sequentially compact. But, how are you saying it is metrizable? I am assuming by Nagata Smirmov Metrizable theorem, but then how are you saying that every first countable space has a countable locally finite basis?

Comment: @user631697 In a first countable space (no metric needed) we have that $S$ sequentially compact is equivalent to $S$ countably compact. So compactness hasn't been shown yet... See my counterexample in the comments

Comment: How can we show that? And does countable compact imply compact?

Comment: @user631697 No, as my counterexample shows.